# Operations with polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I get the following polynomials:

$\alpha = -x^2 -5x +3$

$\beta = -x^3 +5$

$\gamma = 2x+6$

and the next operation:

$\alpha(x) \cdot \beta(x) - 2\gamma(x)$

What should I solve first?

$\alpha(x) \cdot \beta(x)$ or first $-2\gamma(x)$

Comment: Just as with numbers, multiplications and divisions are done before sums and subtractions.

Answer (score 0):

The order of operations still applies.  Note that whether you multiply $\alpha(x)\cdot \beta(x)$ or $2\cdot \gamma(x)$ first doesn't matter, as long as you subtract the products *after* multiplying.

In the same way $a,b,c\in \mathbb R$ are variables that we can recombine as an expression following the order of operations, polynomials are expressions containing variables and are subject to the same order of operations. When combining the like terms of the polynomial $p(x)=\alpha(x)\cdot \beta(x)-2\gamma(x)$ after plugging in each expression, you should again use the correct order of operations.

If you would like to check your work, I put the simplified polynomial below:

> $p(x)=\alpha(x)\cdot \beta(x)-2\gamma(x)$
>  $=[(-x^2-5x+3)(-x^3+5)]-2(2x+6)$
>  $=(x^5-5x^2+5x^4-25x-3x^3+15)-(4x+12)$
>  $=x^5-5x^4-3x^3-5x^2-29x+3$